# problem in saving the foreign key in spring data rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

How to save(POST) the new student in this case

Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, 
                         CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "deptid")
private Department department;
```

Department.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "deptname")
private String deptName;

@Column(name = "depthod")
private String deptHOD;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department",
                            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                                cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, 
                                          CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Student> students;
```

when tried to save department it's saving but when tried to save the new student it throws an error
(deptid could not be null)

I tried to save like this

```
{
"firstName" : "ker",
"lastName" : "ope",
"email" : "ker@gmail.com",
"department" : 6
}
```

Please help me in this case how to save the new student and update the student

*Here the foreign key is deptid in the student table(Entity)

Answer (score 0):

Your property departament is a object not int.
Try select your departament by id and set at student object.

```
Department department  = departmentReṕository.findById(6);
//do validations if ok 
student.setDepartment(department);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you'll have to send whole object of Department with the object of student in your Request body.

Something like below!

```
{
    "firstName" : "ker",
    "lastName" : "ope",
    "email" : "ker@gmail.com",
    "department" : {
        "id" : 6,
        "deptName" : "dept1",
        "deptHOD" : "hod1"
    }
}
```